# How to go directly in the edit section in Backpack-Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

I need that when you to click on an **item** in the **Backpack sidebar** (For ex. Profile),
I immediately can edit the information in this page (For ex. the user who is writing, then the **name**, **surname**, **date of birth** etc.) without going through the table, typical visual of backpack.

In a simple manner:
The user should have the ability to change their profile information whith one click.

How can I do this in Backpack-laravel?
Anyone have any ideas?

Starting code:
**ProfileCrudController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function edit($id)
{
    return parent::edit($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it might be the correct way. But it's the only way I've found to accomplish what I had in mind.

```
  public function index()
  {
    $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'surname',
            'label' => 'Surname',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ]
    ]);
    return parent::edit(Auth::id());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean clicking on the user name in the sidebar should go to editing that user, you can do that by placing the link on it in your `/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/inc/sidebar.blade.php`.